# How to concat two lists in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have two lists `x = ["a","b","c"]` and `y = ["Argentina","Brazil","Canada"]`. I want a list of list like `[["a","Argentina"],["b","Brazil"],["c","Canada"]]`. 
Can Anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like course homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a simpler way, but you could use `zip` to produce a list of tuples, and then `map` that back into a list of lists.

```
Prelude> map (\(a,b) -> [a,b]) $ zip ["a","b","c"] ["Argentina","Brazil","Canada"]
[["a","Argentina"],["b","Brazil"],["c","Canada"]]
```

**Edit**: Daniel Martin points out that `zipWith` is simpler.

```
Prelude> zipWith (\a b -> [a,b]) ["a","b","c"] ["Argentina","Brazil","Canada"]
[["a","Argentina"],["b","Brazil"],["c","Canada"]]
```

Comment: Or skip `map` and just use `zipWith`.

Answer (score 8):

Without seeing your use case I would guess that tuples actually suffice, and are more type safe, hence this is just `zip`

```
x = ["a","b","c"]
y = ["Argentina","Brazil","Canada"]
z = zip x y

Prelude> z
[("a","Argentina"),("b","Brazil"),("c","Canada")]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use

```
zipWith (\x y -> [x,y])
```